# Noxious Revival and Street Wraith interaction

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-modern

I’m asking myself if I can get back a cycled [Street Wraith](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStreet%20Wraith%5d) using the cycle ability and a [Noxious Revival](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNoxious%20Revival%5d).

The idea is:

- Use cycle ability, pay two life and discard, the ability goes on the stack
- Play Noxious Revival targeting Wraith in the graveyard to put it on top of the deck
- Resolve Noxious Revival
- Resolve the cycle ability to draw the Wraith

The discard part of cycle is part of the activation cost? So does it resolve before the ability?

The reason to do that is to take advantage of life loss in a deck like death's shadow

Comment: You keep using the word "trigger" in a ways that don't make sense to me. Drawing a card is an effect, not a trigger.

Comment: @Acccumulation you are right, I will change in ability on the stack and after all is an activated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes, you can do this.**

Street Wraith has the ability

> Cycling—Pay 2 life.

which (as the reminder text states) is shorthand<sup>[702.28a](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Cycling)</sup> for

> Pay 2 life, Discard this card: Draw a card.

Since this is an activated ability, everything to the left of the colon (:) character is the *cost* that must be paid to use the ability.<sup>[602.1a](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Activated_ability)</sup>  You pay the cost (discard the card and pay 2 life) and the ability is placed on the stack.

Once the ability hits the stack, it follows all the usual rules for resolution - including allowing players to respond by using different spells or abilities.<sup>[602.2b](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Activated_ability)</sup>  At this point you can use Noxious Revival; it also goes on the stack.

Once everybody passes priority, the spells resolve in LIFO order: Noxious Revival resolves first, letting you place the Street Wraith on top of your library, followed by Street Wraith's cycling ability, which lets you draw a card.